# How to create an iOS8 Popover as per WWDC2014 session 214

Tags: ios, popover

I want to create a popover like the one shown in the WWDC2014 session 214 - see picture below from the video.  I have tried to implement exactly what they suggest but no matter what I try the popover always appears in full screen.

However if I rotate the device and then rotate back the popover appears as a smaller popover but the views all seem to get confused.

So a couple of questions:

1. Is this a known bug and are there any workarounds?
2. Where can I find the sample code used in the video?
3. Does anyone have a working implementation using the new iOS8 methods?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK looks like the advice in the WWDC video is incorrect and if I change the order of the calls then things work as expected. As long as I call the `presentViewController` API last things seem to work OK which seems to be at odds with the commentary in the video.

```
UIPopoverPresentationController *pc = [_dbPickerViewController popoverPresentationController];
pc.delegate = self;
pc.sourceView = self;

[_detailViewController presentViewController:_dbPickerViewController animated: YES completion: nil];
```

Hope this helps someone else.